# PHP How to divide 8500 files in to folders

Tags: php

I have about 8500 PDF files that are stored on my server.
I would like to dived them like this in sub folder:

- 0 - 100 > folder 1
- 101 - 200 > folder 2
- 201 - 300 > folder 3
- ...
- 1001 - 1100 > folder 11
- 1101 - 1200 > folder 12
- 1201 - 1300 > folder 13
- ...

I know how to make an new directory and move files between folders. But what is the best way to detect into which folders to put them. And second how to use the correct if function to see if they are present in a certain folder.

[image]

Comment: If 0-100 is folder 1, how can 1001-1100 be folder 10? What folder should have 200 files?

Comment: What if you were to create a loop (containing $fileCounter & $dirCounter) that ran through 100 files at a time, and if the file name = the loop's $fileCounter count, move that into the current $dirCounter's count directory? Of course, increase the $dirCounter every 100 loops.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this code. As I understand it, it's a one time use code. Once the files are moved you have no use of the code. If you only use a code once it has to make it much much more efficient than doing it manually. A good guess is, this job takes about 20-30 minutes to do manually. It's been 20 minutes since you posted. You could have had it done by now.

Comment: @Andreas 30 minutes to manually move 8500 files? I'd hire you. =D ... Seriously though, it takes less time to code and you remove the element of human error. Also can re-run or easily refactor if you decide to change the directory structures. Also, this is a programming related question afterall.

Comment: Yes but still, it's a quick job to move files. It's daunting, but fairly quick. Once you moved a few hundred you will get in to this "zen state" and just know exactly what buttons to push. I believe we already have proven that it takes more than 30 minutes to code it given when this question was posted and that OP should have done some tries and research himself first

Comment: And you can't really use the code again since the files are scattered in 85 folders, that means you need to start over from scratch again and build a code that gathers the files again from the folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work (not tested)

```
<?php
$listOfFiles = ["100.pdf", "200.pdf", "201.pdf"]; // populate this using glob / opendir

foreach ($listOfFiles as $file) {

    // intval will return just the number part of the filename
    // division with 100 + ceil will make 100 = 1, 200 = 2, 201 = 3 aso
    $folderName = ceil(intval($file) / 100);

    // make folder
    if (!file_exists($folderName)) {
        mkdir($folderName, 0755, true);
    }

    // move file if does not exists
    if (!file_exists($foldername."/".$file)) {
        rename($file, $foldername."/".$file);
    } else {
        // maybe delete it
        unlink($file);
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems a potential start, but still need to verify that OP's files exist in a given directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all files into one big array, then use array_chunk() to split up.

```
$arr = []; // assume all your filename to be in here
$chunked = array_chunk($arr, 100);
```

Then chunked will be a new array with 85 arrays in it, where each of the 85 inner arrays contains 100 filenames.

---

Added by Andreas to show the true potential of this method (in my opinion).

```
$arr = range(1,1000); // as temporary substitute for glob()
$chunked = array_chunk($arr, 100);
//Var_dump($chunked);

Foreach($chunked as $key => $subarr){
    $destfolder = "/folder " . ($key+1) . "/";
    Foreach($subarr as $file){
        // Move $file to $destfolder.
    }
}
```

This means you don't have to "calculate" what folder the file goes to.
It's always `$key+1` since arrays start at 0.
And the destination folder string only needs to be created 85 times compared to 8500 with the other methods posted here.

Feel free to remove this Lars if you don't like it or agree with it.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question? He's asking how to move the files and verify them, not how to create an array of files.

Comment: @Adam to some degree it does answer OP. It splits the files in chunkes of 100. But I'm not sure what will happen with file 113 in the image of question with this method.

Comment: the method is documented (last array will have the remaining items below $size parameter). @Adam: You're wrong. He writes "i know how to create folders and move files"... so THAT was NOT the question.

Comment: @Lars do you mind if I add some code to your answer? I think your code snippet has more to offer than what you show here

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested code, but all the logic is there to do what you need. If you need to move files instead of `copy`, use the `rename()` function instead.

You would probably need to modify the `getDir()` function to return an absolute path to the new directory as well.

```
<?php
$files = [ 
  '/foo/35.pdf', 
  '/bar/135.pdf', 
  '/foo/235.pdf', 
  '/baz/1035.pdf', 
  '/foo/1135.pdf', 
  '/bar/1235.pdf'
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
  // Get the base name of the file.
  $basename = basename($file);

  // Get the directory the file should go into.
  $dir = getDir($basename);

  // Make the directory if it doesn't exist.
  if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir);
  }

  // Create a string with the new path
  $path = $dir.'/'.$file;

  // Copy the file if it doesn't exists already
  if (!file_exists($newpath) {
    copy($file, $newpath);
  }
}

function getDir($file) {
  $num = (int)strstr($file, '.', true);
  return floor($num / 100)+1;
}
```

:edit: As Andreas pointed out, this would put `100` in directory 2, as this solution groups 0 - 99 instead of 1 - 100. If 1 based directories are a hard requirement, Lawrence's answer is a good reference.

Comment: Your math is slightly off. If the filename is `100` your function returns folder 2, not 1 as OP requested.

Comment: @Andreas Good catch, I'll add a disclaimer. This and the other answers should get him going.

Comment: Why not just use `ceil($num/100)`

Comment: Don't you think it's funny how you want to remove the "human error" by creating a code, and then your code places 85 files in the wrong folder?

Comment: @Andreas I guess you don't have anything better to do. Read the first sentence. I was helping the guy get in the ballpark. Your suggestion of doing it manually is the biggest joke here by far.